# Send a email base on a taxonomy term

Tags: wp-mail

I like to have a email send if a custom post is created/updated if it has  custom taxonomy **term**.

The here is the CPT, taxonomy and term.

- Custom Post Type:  Call
- Custom taxonomy:   call_type
- Custom Term:       In progress

The code below work fine for just sending a mail based on the CTP.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Add Hooks for Email 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_action('new_to_publish', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
add_action('post_updated', 'send_emails_on_new_event');
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  SET EMAIL FROM ADDRESS
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function change_mail_from() {
    return "noreply@abc.com";
}
add_filter ("wp_mail_from", "change_mail_from");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  SET EMAIL FROM NAME
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function change_from_name() {
    return "ABC";
}
add_filter ("wp_mail_from_name", "change_from_name");
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  SET EMAIL TYPE TO HTML
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Send emails on event publication
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function send_emails_on_new_event($post_id)
{
    global $post;
    $post           =   get_post($post_id);
    $post_id        =   $post->ID;
    $post_type      =   'call'; //post, page, attachment or whatever other CPT you may have
    $post_term      =   ''
    $author         =   get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $mf_area        =   $author->mf_area;
    $author_mail    =   $author->user_email;
    $author_name    =   $author->mf_d_name;
    $ac_name        =   get_post_meta( $post_id, '_call_8', true);
    $ac_email       =   get_post_meta( $post_id, '_call_9', true);
    $rc_email       =   get_post_meta( $post_id, '_call_12', true);
    $rc_name        =   get_post_meta( $post_id, '_call_13', true);
    $mtm_email      =   'support@abc.com';
    $emails         =   "$author_mail, $ac_email, $mtm_email"; //If you want to send to site administrator, use $emails = get_option('admin_email');
    $title          =   wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_title($post_id,));
    $url            =   home_url();
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Email lay out
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    ob_start(); ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                a {
                    color: #ff3333;
                    font: 1.5rem;
                    line-height: 2rem;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                Hi 
            </p>
            <p>
                Ref number <?php echo $title ;?> has been created.
            </p>

            <p>
                <strong>Details:</strong><br />
                <a href="<?php echo $url ;?>">Log in to track this call.</a><br/>
            </p>
            <p>
                Regards,<br />
                ABC
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    if(get_post_type($post) === $post_type)
    wp_mail($emails, "New Item listed on Fit It List. Ref number $title", $message);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  End Fire mail on post page and CPT
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Can someone please help to make the script work for terms as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)?

```
if( get_post_type($post) === $post_type && has_term( 'In progress', 'call_type', $post ) )
    wp_mail($emails, "New Item listed on Fit It List. Ref number $title", $message);
```

Comment: Thank you working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If this helped you solve it, marking it as the accepted answer would be appreciated.